# Drawing rooted binary (search) trees

Tags: graph-drawing, binary-trees

I am looking for an (elegant, fast, etc.) algorithm to draw a binary tree, where the root is distinguished, as well as the left and right children of each node. A typical example is a binary search tree. The goal is to have the densest possible drawing, with the constraints:

1. The child of a node is below its parent, and in particular the root is alone on top of the drawing;
2. Each node is symmetric: If it has two children, it must be centered between its children and the children must be vertically aligned;
3. If a node has a single child, the node and its child are not horizontally aligned: the child must be either on the left or on the right;
4. Edges between nodes don't go through nodes;
5. Two nodes are at a minimal distance, say $1$.

The goal is to compute coordinates for each node. The way to make the actual drawing, using any relevant format (SVG, PS, TikZ, etc.), and is not part of my question.

**Is there a known (efficient) algorithm for such a drawing?**

For now, I use the following algorithm, in which all nodes at the same height in the binary tree are vertically aligned, and :

- Recursively, compute the drawing (= coordinates) of the left and right children of the root;
- For each child and each height, compute the leftmost and the rightmost nodes;
- For each height, compute the minimal distance between the left child and the right child for the distance between nodes to respect the minimal distance;
- Take the maximum of these minimal distances ($1$ if one child is empty), and compute from these a shift to apply to the coordinates of both children;
- Finally compute the coordinates of the root, vertically centered between its two children.

This gives reasonably good results, but does not ensure constraint 4. It may also not construct the densest possible solution, since it forces all nodes of a same height to be vertically aligned. And it is not particularly elegant, though this notion is of course ill-defined.